# Adding roles management to Node JS API + Angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt

I'm building my application, with Node JS back end and Angular 6 front end.

I implemented registration / login with JWT. Now, I would like to add roles to protect my routes (user, coach, admin), what is the best way to do that?
A user can have multiple roles (admin + coach for example).

This is my middleware to check auth :

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        req.userData = {
            email: decodedToken.email,
            userId: decodedToken.user_id
        }
        next()
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: 'You're not authenticated.'
        })
    }
}
```

And this is how I create the token when the user logs in:

```
const token = jwt.sign({
            email: fetchedUser.email,
            userId: fetchedUser.id
        }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: '1h'
        })
```

I thought about adding the role via the token when the user logs in. But how to handle that side Angular? And protect some routes via another middlewares

Example :

```
router.get('/:coachId', checkAuth, ***<!>hasRoles('Admin')<!>***, coachCtrl.getCoach);
```

I would like to add another middleware that handles checking roles in addition to the check-auth.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: refere this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025613/role-based-jwt-authorization

Comment: I already read this post but I have trouble adapting it with my own code: - /

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt-permissions try this one

Comment: Unfortunately this is the first time I have to manage the roles with JWT, and there is no concrete example of the npm package: - /